# Dart use specific instance as parent class

Tags: dart, inheritance

I want to create a `B` class from specific instance of `A` class is this somehow possible?

```dart
class A {
  int id;
  A();
}

class B extends A {
  String param;
  B();
}
```

Its possible `b = B()` which it can have an id from parent `A` class (it has its own `A` class as parent), but what if I have `a = A()` and I want to use this specific `a` which is `A` class as my new `B` class parent. Is this possible (so then the new `B` class id will be equal to `a.id`)? some sort of manually setting `super` of `B`.

Comment: No, and it doesn't make sense to do that.  Inheritance doesn't work that way.  This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); exactly why do you think you need `B` to derive from a specific *instance* of `A`?  Why can't `B` construct an appropriate `A` instead?  Perhaps consider adding `operator ==` (and `hashCode`) instead?  Or perhaps you should use composition instead of inheritance and let `B` forward to an `A` member?

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, I'm writing sort of plugin and I can't create `B` before `A` is created. Wanted to know if its possible. It would have made my situation easier to solve at first glance. I will look into composition.

Comment: That still doesn't really explain why you care about a specific *instance* instead of caring about objects comparing equal.  You'd never create `B` before `A` anyway; constructing a `B` object fully constructs `A` first.

Comment: the core part passes instance of `A` (which is related to an element in frontend) to my plugin, I want to extend the functionality so created class `B` which extends `A` but with extending I can't have the same instance of `A` as parent (related to frontend element) creating another instance of `A` doesn't make sense also going with composit pattern has the problem of not having access to `A` protected methods.